# Extract lines in a log file that are greater than a value

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have filtered a server log, and would like to save the IP + code to a new text file that only contains lines where the code is above a value of 1000.

```
Example log file:
1.1.1.1 1000
2.2.2.2 2000
3.3.3.3 950
4.4.4.4 800
5.5.5.5 3000

Example output: 
1.1.1.1 1000
2.2.2.2 2000
5.5.5.5 3000
```

Comment: If you mean "_above a value of 1000_" then you won't have 1000 in your output. Did you mean "_at or above a value of 1000_"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this awk line:

```
awk '$NF >= 1000 {print $0}' log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in *perl*:

This command will print the numbers *equal and more than* 1000:

```
perl -ne 'print if grep {$_>=1000} /(\d{3,})/g' log.txt
2.2.2.2 2000
5.5.5.5 3000
```

This command will print the numbers *more than* 1000

```
perl -ne 'print if grep {$_>1000} /(\d{3,})/g' log.txt
1.1.1.1 1000
2.2.2.2 2000
5.5.5.5 3000
```

Comment: Why not simply this: `perl -nae 'print if $F[-1] >= 1000 log.txt`'

Comment: And if you don't want splitting: `perl -ne 'print if (/(\d{3,})$/)[0] >= 1000' log.txt`